# Where I can find Primefaces 3.4.1 bundle package (dev package)?

Tags: primefaces, broken-links, debug-build

The official link in the [official Primefaces download page](https://www.primefaces.org/downloads/#main) is broken, and in Maven repository I can find only the bin, not the bundle.

The bundle package is a bin package with the source code and the javadocs.

Someone can point me to a safe link, if it exists?

Comment: What bundle / file do you mean?

Comment: @JasperdeVries if you see the link, for every version of Primefaces there's the classical bin package, a source package and a "bundle" package, that is the bin package with sources and javadocs, for debugging and developing.

Comment: https://repository.primefaces.org/org/primefaces/primefaces/3.4.1/ ?

Comment: @JasperdeVries nope, the link https://repository.primefaces.org/org/primefaces/primefaces/3.4.1/ only contains the bin with only .class files, and the source package. No "bundle".

Comment: https://github.com/primefaces/primefaces/tree/3_4_1 ? https://github.com/primefaces/primefaces/archive/refs/tags/3_4_1.zip ?

Comment: @JasperdeVries are you suggesting to create it myself? I don't know how to add javadocs

Comment: I have absolutely no idea what you are looking for. I'm not suggesting anything.

Comment: @JasperdeVries "Primefaces can be downloaded manually or via maven. Bundles contain binaries, sources, api and tag docs." - https://www.primefaces.org/downloads/#main

Comment: You have the source code for 3.4.1 so what more do you need?  What is in the "bin" that isn't right there with the JAR and Sources?

Comment: I highly recommend not to use older version as it comes with security risks, a lot of security risks have been patched in later versions.

Comment: @fareed It's an old project and cannot be changed, unless the client explicitly request this need.

Comment: if it is possible make the client aware of the security risks. Otherwise, I suggest you try to contact primefaces team

Comment: See this answer to know about one security risk that I struggled with  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48314621/jsf-cryptojacking-malware

Comment: @fareed I'm a programmer. It's not me that talks with the client. I informed the boss. Thank you anyway for you suggestion, but we are a bit off-topic. I suggest you to start a chat if you want to continue.