# JSF App: Second server request not submitted to server after upgrade from WAS 8.5 to 9.0

Tags: jsf, websphere, myfaces

Caveat: I haven't used JSF since college, and that was longer ago than I care to admit, so pretend I'm brand new with the technology.

Background:
We are upgrading from Java 1.7 and WAS 8.5 with My Faces 2.2.4.
We are upgrading to Java 1.8 and WAS 9.0.

MF version is staying the same, and we're using the same library files that are found on 8.5.  We are using a Shared Library for the files, as recommended by IBM.

Everything works fine under WAS 8.5.  The application works as expected on my local machine, and all functionality seems good.

When running under the upgraded server the JSF application exhibits some unusual behavior.

When clicking any button that results in a server call, the first time the button is clicked, everything works fine.  After that, every button you click, regardless of its actual function, no matter if it's an action, or action listener, performs the same function with the same server response as the first button click.

Even if you change the criteria from the server call, the response from the server remains the same.  I did validate that the updated criteria makes it into the request by looking at the request and response objects, but no matter what I click (even if it calls a completely different server side function), the response is the same and the screen state resets itself to match the moment the first button click was made.  Meaning all fields on the screen are reset to contain the data that was in them at the time of that click, even if that data has been updated.

I'm absolutely flummoxed.  I've been trying to research this issue, but frankly, I don't even know what questions to ask.

Update: We've done some additional testing, and determined the second request isn't actually hitting the server at all (we don't see the added debug lines after the first attempt).  So what we're seeing isn't so much a second postback as it is the first one being repeated.

Additionally, we're seeing the same behavior in multiple browsers.

Comment: I'm curious why you don't use WAS9 default MyFaces? Shouldn't that also be 2.2? What happens if you use WAS provided library?

Comment: BTW did you set classloader to PARENT_FIRST? https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/was/9.0.5?topic=files-configuring-javaserver-faces-22

Comment: @Nikola thank you for the comment.  We removed the shared library, and let it pull the default.  That didn't make any difference in the behavior.  I did validate that the class loading is set to parent first, and it is.

Comment: how about web.xml javax.faces.SERIALIZE_SERVER_STATE? it should be set to true most likely

Comment: @Nikola We didn't have that set in the web.xml, which, if I'm reading the docs right means it defaults to false.  I tried setting it to true explicitly and it made no difference in the behavior.  If it matters, we have 'javax.faces.STATE_SAVING_METHOD' set to 'server'.

Comment: Additionally, I've found that this behavior seems to be related to the session.  If I logout of the application and then log back in with a fresh session (not even a new browser window, just log out and log back in), the application acts fine until I click a button, and then it resumes acting as before with the new button click.

Comment: Digging into this some more, we discovered that the issue is a compatibility issue with the upgraded version of JSF that comes with the server and our version of Primefaces.  We upgraded to PF 5.3 (which is still really old) and now most of the broken functionality is working.  The only thing still broken is the command link, but I expect that's just a coding issue.

Comment: be careful with PrimeFaces 5.3 it has BIG vulnerability https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.primefaces/primefaces/5.3 and good luck

Comment: @Nikola We're going to push the version up some more and see how close to the newest we can get before it breaks everything again.  Thank you for your assistance, and for the word on the vulnerability.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Posting our findings for posterity.

It turns out this was a compatibility issue with the version of PrimeFaces we were using (3.3.1).  We upgraded Primefaces to 5.3 (still a really old version) and functionality returned as expected, with the exception of command links not working at all (I expect a coding issue brought on by the upgrade).  However, the problem of all buttons doing the same thing, and returning the same results over and over again has been corrected.  We're seeing our debug logs from the server being actively generated which a step forward.

For the record, I would always recommend using the newest version of Primefaces (or any component) you can, as there could be vulnerabilities in older versions (as pointed out in the comments).

Comment: Be advised that 5.3 enables remote code execution (even if you DON'T use PF component that is guilty). Upgrade to 6.0

Comment: Indeed. See also https://stackoverflow.com/q/48314621